# ORA-00904: "ID": invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, ddl, create-table

I am trying to create a table with a foreign key. I keep getting `ORA-00904` error. What am I doing wrong? Is it because the table of the foreign key is not yet created?

```
CREATE TABLE ingredients( 
   ingredient_id       number(2,0),
   ingredient          VARCHAR2(55) NOT NULL,
   quantity_required   VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
   optional_ingredient VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT pk_ingr_id PRIMARY KEY(ingredient_id),
   CONSTRAINT fk_ingredient_list FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES ingredient_list(id)
);
```

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the following line:

```
CONSTRAINT fk_ingredient_list FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES ingredient_list(id)
```

Your table has no column named "id". I assume you meant to write

```
CONSTRAINT fk_ingredient_list FOREIGN KEY(ingredient_id) REFERENCES ingredient_list(id)
```

EDIT:
Additionally, as you suspected yourself, if you want to reference the `ingredient_list` table, you must create it before creating the `ingredients` table that references it.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, so i should create the table first and then add the foreign key to the table later on after creating all the tables ?

Comment: not necessarily, but you should keep the order in mind. Before creating a constraint on table X to reference table Y, you make sure that both X and Y exist.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had used quotes in the table creation like below:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (
"ID"                   NUMBER(19, 0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
"OPT_LOCK_VERSION"     NUMBER(19, 0),
-- etc.
```

And then tried creating similar constraint as in the question. That resulted to the same ORA-00904 error. When I modified my table creation script by removing those unnecessary quotes, the constraint creation started to work.

Answer (score 0):

We never know but in my case I had this exception no matter what name I gave my column.
I had a library with EF which pointed on the proper database. The entities were correct.

But on the client part (a web application), the connection string pointed to another database!
A stupid mistake, it was hard to pinpoint this silly misgave....

So please have a look at the connection string FIRST :)