# save duplicated records in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I starting to learn django and I have this newbie issue:
I have to models the relation between the model is one to many. One provider must have many DetailLoad.

I create a form for the DetailLoad where I only need to save the id_proveedor (FK), anio and mes.
But when I try to save the form a validation error is displayed **"detail Load for this provider already exists"**.

Models.py

```
    class Provider(models.Model):
        id_proveedor = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='id_proveedor')
        nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
        tipo = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
        asignado_a = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, verbose_name='Asignado a')
        moneda = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True)
        class Meta:
            managed = False
            db_table = 'mpc_proveedores'

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.nombre

class DetailLoad(models.Model):
    id_proveedor = models.ForeignKey(Proveedor,db_column='id_proveedor', primary_key=True, verbose_name='Proveedor')
    anio = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    mes = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    f_carga = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Fecha de carga')
    usuario = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    registros = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True,verbose_name='Cant. de Registros')
    num_codigos = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True,verbose_name='Cant. codigos')
    lista_codigos = models.CharField(max_length=2500, blank=True, verbose_name='Lista de Codigos')
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'mpc_detalle_carga_archivo'
```

the definition of the form that I use to save the data:

```
class NewDetLoadForm(forms.ModelForm):
      def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
       super(NewDetRecForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
       self.helper = FormHelper(self)
       self.helper.layout.append(Submit('save','Grabar'))
       self.helper.layout = Layout(
        Fieldset('',
                 'id_proveedor',
                 'anio',
                 'mes',
                 Submit('save','Grabar'),
                )
       )


      class Meta:
        model = DetalleRecepcion
```

my view:

```
def NewDetLoadView(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
       drform = NewDetLoadForm(request.POST or none)
       if drform.is_valid():
          drform.save()
          return HttpResponseRedirect('/monitor/')
    else:
       drform = NewDetLoadForm()

    return render_to_response('newdetload.html',locals(),
                               context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I need to be capable to save records, selecting the provider and filling the other two fields even if are duplicate rows.
By the way is a legacy database, the tables doesn't have constraints or any kind of relationship another tables.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In the `DetailLoad` model you are setting `Proveedor` ForeignKey and also making it a primary key. The primary keys are always unique that is why you can not add another entry. You need to remove the `primary_key=True` from:

```
id_proveedor = models.ForeignKey(Proveedor,db_column='id_proveedor', primary_key=True, verbose_name='Proveedor')
```

In django the primary keys are automatically generated and you don't need to define them in your models. The primary keys can be accessed with `id` or `pk` attribute.

Comment: Thanks, I follow your advice,but now I get the error **ORA-00904: "MPC_DETAIL_LOAD"."ID": invalid identifier**

Comment: To perform that you should install and use south app (if Django version < 1.7) or do migration (if Django version >= 1.7), or you should manually alter table by some oracle tools. Because data in you DB would not change if you just remove `primary_key=True` in your model. Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339464/ora-00904-id-invalid-identifier