# Django form insert record instead of update record

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I am having some issues trying to update some records in Django:
When i try to update some record, the app insert a new one, I don't know why i have this behavior.

Model

```
class DetalleRecepcion(models.Model):
    id_proveedor = models.ForeignKey(Proveedor,db_column='id_proveedor',primary_key=True, verbose_name='Proveedor')
    anio = models.IntegerField( null=False)
    mes = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Mes')
    fecha_recepcion = models.DateField(verbose_name='Fecha Recepcion')
    usuario = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    num_archivos = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, verbose_name='No de archivos')
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'mpc_detalle_recepcion'
```

view:

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def DetRecView(request):
    idp = request.GET.get('i')
    anio = request.GET.get('a')
    mes = request.GET.get('m')
    if request.method == 'POST':
       r = DetalleRecepcion.objects.get(id_proveedor=idp,anio=anio,mes=mes)
       form = DetRecForm(request.POST or None, instance =r)
       if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
          return HttpResponse('<script type="text/javascript">window.close()</script>')
    else:
       r = DetalleRecepcion.objects.get(id_proveedor=idp,anio=anio,mes=mes)
       r.usuario = request.user
       form = DetRecForm(instance=r)

    return render_to_response('detrec.html',
                              {'form':form},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Form:

```
class DetRecForm(forms.ModelForm):
      fecha_recepcion = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput(),)
      def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
          super(DetRecForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
          self.helper = FormHelper(self)
          self.helper.layout = Layout(
           Field('id_proveedor',
                 'anio',
                 'mes',
                 'usuario',
                 readonly = True
                 ),
           Fieldset('',
                    'fecha_recepcion',
                    'num_archivos',
                    Submit('save','Grabar'),
                    HTML('<a class="btn btn-danger" id="cerrar">Cancelar</a>')
                    )
          )
      class Meta:
          model = DetalleRecepcion
```

I use the same view and form definition for others models to render edit forms and with this other models works great and the records are updated.
I don't understand what it's happen.
I rewrite the form, view definition for this model and I don't know what it is the problem.
The database is a legacy database and the tables doesn't have any kind of relationship or constraint.
By the way I am using Django crispy form

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you using same form for create and update views, then you need provide clean method on your unique field and raise ValidationError when object exists.

But in your case, I assuming you using Composite Primary Key on fields: id_proveedor, num_archivos, you should override clean method of the whole form:

```
class DetRecForm(forms.ModelForm):
    fecha_recepcion = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DetRecForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('id_proveedor',
                  'anio',
                  'mes',
                  'usuario',
                  readonly=True
            ),
            Fieldset('',
                     'fecha_recepcion',
                     'num_archivos',
                     Submit('save', 'Grabar'),
                     HTML('<a class="btn btn-danger" id="cerrar">Cancelar</a>')
            )
        )

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(DetRecForm, self).clean()

        id_proveedor = self.cleaned_data['id_proveedor']
        num_archivos = self.cleaned_data['num_archivos']

        qs = self.Meta.model.objects.filter(id_proveedor=id_proveedor, num_archivos=num_archivos)
        if self.instance:
            qs = qs.exclude(pk=self.instance.id)
        if qs.count() > 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError(u'Such object exists!')

        return cleaned_data

    class Meta:
        model = DetalleRecepcion
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have a round of one month with python and django and I make a lot of newbie errors and theres some things that I don't have idea where to put it. This clean function where I have to write it in the form definition or in the view. and how can I call this clean function

Comment: In method body I called super(DetRecForm, self).clean(), so you should put it in DetRecForm declaration, and you shouldn't manually call it, that will run while form validation automatically because you override parent class method 'clean'.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I don't want to bother you, nut I have another issue. this model have a one to many relationship with another model. one provider can have many detrec records. but I get the error id_proveedor already registered. A couple days ago I post that thread [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26475096/save-duplicated-records-in-django/26475251#26475251). I understand the exception but I don't know how to insert the data. I need to insert id_proveedor, anio and mes, but for the primary key i can't make it. Any idea how can i insert records.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get object by pk for instance

```
DetalleRecepcion.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])
```