# Django create and edit page using one template

Tags: python, django, templates

I run into a problem that every time when i save on the edit page, it doesn't go to the url but instead asking me to input the field i want to hide.

model.py

```
class Building(models.Model):
 # Name of the project
 name = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name='Project ID')
 # The address of the building
 address = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Address')
 # The client name for this project
 client = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 # The contact number for the project
 contact = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

forms.py

```
# The form to edit building details
class UpdateBuildingForm(forms.ModelForm):
  name = forms.CharField(label='Name', max_length=25, widget=forms.TextInput)
  client = forms.CharField(label='Client', max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput)
  contact = forms.CharField(label='Contact', max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput)
  address = forms.CharField(label='Address', max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput)

  class Meta:
     model = Building
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                   # e.g: /projectmonitor/
                   url(r'^$', views.BuildingSummary.as_view(), name='buildings'),
                   # url to add new building
                   url(r'building/new/$', views.BuildingCreate.as_view(), name='new_building'),
                   # e.g: /projectmonitor/5
                   url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.BuildingUpdate.as_view(), name='detail'),
```

views.py:

```
# The building create view
class BuildingCreate(generic.CreateView):
    model = Building
    form_class = UpdateBuildingForm
    template_name = "buildings/details.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
       self.object = form.save(commit=False)
       self.object.save()
       return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('projectmonitor:buildings'))

 # The building update view
class BuildingUpdate(generic.UpdateView):
    model = Building
    form_class = UpdateBuildingForm
    template_name = "buildings/details.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
       """
       Update the building details after editing
       :param form: The building form
       :return: Redirect to the building summary page
       """
       self.object = form.save(commit=False)
       self.object.save()
       return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('projectmonitor:buildings'))
```

and template

```
<form action="{{ action }}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
            {{ error }}
        {% endfor %}
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
            {% if not form.name.value  %}
                <p><label class="standard-label" for="id_name">Name:</label>
                {{ form.name|add_field_style:'width: 65%;margin-left: 10px;float:left;' }}</p>
            {% endif %}
            <p><label class="standard-label" for="id_address">Address:</label>
                {{ form.address|add_field_style:'width: 65%;margin-left: 10px;float:left;' }}</p>

            <p><label class="standard-label" for="id_client">Client:</label>
                {{ form.client|add_field_style:'width: 65%;margin-left: 10px;float:left;' }}</p>

            <p><label class="standard-label" for="id_contact">Contact:</label>
                {{ form.contact|add_field_style:'width: 65%;margin-left: 10px;float:left;' }}</p>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
    </form>
```

Both edit and create shares the same template. The name field is a unique key for each building, once user creates a building, I don't want them to change it, so I try to hide it on the edit view. but when I change other fields and try to save it, it always pops an empty name field and ask me to enter the name. Does anyone have any suggestions? thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26492650/3033586

Comment: so in your case, when updating object, you have to provide initial data to this field or use another form (with excluded field) and set it later in your view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `readonly` attribute on the name field.

Try adding the following `__init__` method in your `UpdateBuildingForm` class:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(UpdateBuildingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
    if instance and instance.pk:
        self.fields['name'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
```

Moreover, you can also set the `disable` attribute.

Edit:
based on @madzohan's comment, you can add a clean_name method to ensure the name field will not change on form level.

```
def clean_name(self):
    if self.instance: 
        return self.instance.name
    else: 
        return self.fields['name']
```

Comment: add `def clean_name` and  show how to provide initial data for this field and this will be correct answer, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. For more information about `clean_<field_name>()`: [Form and field validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/validation/)